# What does it mean for resistance, as it appears in Ohm's law, to be an integral, evaluated over the body as a whole?

Tags: electrical-resistance, differential-equations, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction, porous-media

In literature I read:

[image]

The three linear flux laws mentioned are:

[image]

As seen, a correspondence exist between the hydraulic conductivity $K$, thermal conductivity $\lambda$, and electrical conductivity $\sigma$. In terms of electrical resistivity, $\rho$, Ohm's law could be written
$$-\nabla V = \rho \vec i$$

I believe the differential equation being refered to in the last sentence is Fourier's partial differential equation of heat conduction -- [the heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation).

I do not know what are, or what is meant by, "integral equations and flow nets" in the last sentence (for which "Ohm's law is inherently well suited").

**So my questions are**: What does it mean for resistance, as it appears in Ohm's law, to be an integral, evaluated over the body as a whole? What are integral equations and why is Ohm's law well suited for them? Why is Ohm's law not well suited for the heat equation (the differential equation)?

Comment: Google indicates that the first passage is from [this article](https://olemiss.edu/projects/sciencenet/saltnet/wel_hydraulics_history_1998.pdf)? Why do you think Narasimhan is referring to the Ohm's Law formulation $\vec i=-\sigma\nabla V$, as listed in your table? The mention of "resistance" in the quotation indicates that he's referring to the formulation $I=V/R$.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Yes, that's the article. I didn't pick up on the difference on terminology "resistance" versus "resistivity". I wrote Ohm's law the way I have seen it written (a poor assumption on my part), & I did not see it written anywhere in the paper. I suppose $V=RI$ is somehow related to $-\nabla V = \rho \vec i$?

Comment: I don't understand what Narasimhan is trying to say, since—as your table indicates—Ohm's law can be written for a local differential element in a manner analogous to the other equations. I think it's also poor form to write a scientific article discussing the nature and implication of certain equations and not actually write the corresponding equations, as it can produce just this type of confusion.